# Is the word 'mutable variable' in java concurrency programming same as the meaning in functional programming?

Tags: java, multithreading, functional-programming, locking, mutable

In the book 'Java Concurrency in Practice', when talking about 'locking and visibility', the author said:

> We can now give the other reason for the rule requiring all threads to synchronize on the same lock when accessing a shared mutable variable—to guarantee that values written by one thread are made visible to other threads. Otherwise, if a thread reads a variable without holding the appropriate lock, it might see a stale value.

Here is the figure:
[image: Figure 3.1. Visibility guarantees for synchronization.]

I'm curious about the meaning of 'mutable' here. As per my knowledge in functional programming, 'immutable' means unchangeable and 'mutable' opposite. The variable x in the figure is what the author refers to as shared mutable variable. Is x(an integer or some other similar) mutable?

Comment: You have to distinguish between the *variable* and the *value*. A variable can be mutable (as in you can set its value, which you can for any non-`final` variable), but the value is immutable (e.g. `Integer` is immutable, `List` is (possibly) mutable). But a `final` variable with a mutable value is still considered mutable.

Comment: Immutable means that if you change the value of your object, you're actually creating a new object.

Comment: @Nathan no, immutability means that you can't change the value (i.e. "if you change the value" can never happen). You *can* create a new object, but that doesn't affect the value of the first one.

Comment: @AndyTurner That's what I wanted to convey, but I should've said "if you change the value of your variable", right?

Comment: @Nathan but then it's a mutable variable.

Comment: @AndyTurner If I write `String v = "toto"; v = "tata";`, I changed the value of my variable v. Before, it was a pointer on the object `String(toto)`, now it's a pointer on the other object `String(tata)`. Mutability is more about the objects than the variable IMO, and `final`or `not final` are about the variables.

Comment: @Nathan mutability is about whether there is an observable change of state. That change of state can be because you assign a new value to a variable, or because the internal state of the value assigned to the variable changes. Either way, state changes, so it's mutable.

Comment: So, in `int i = 0;`, i is a mutable variable and 0 is an immutable value.In `final int j = 0`, j is an immutable variable and 0 is still an immutable value.In `Car c = new Car()`, the variable c is mutable, but whether its value(the new initialized car) is immutable or not depends on the class Car's implementation.In `final Car c = new Car()`, the variable c is immutable and its value is as said. Am i right?

Comment: @AndyTurner So we agree that `v` is mutable in my example but not `String(tata)`. Let's leave it at that or we're gonna have to move to chat ^^

Comment: @iamswf Yes, you are.

Comment: @iamswf yes, up to `final Car c = new Car()`. You can't describe a variable with a mutable value as "immutable", because you may be able to change the state of `c`, depending upon the implementation of `Car`.

Comment: @AndyTurner I understand that.So in fact, what does the author want to say is about whether the variable x(the variable) is final. And as far as i know,  immutability in functional programming is about whether an object's state(which I consider more of the value) is changeable. Am I right?

Comment: @iamswf given that the diagram shows assignment to the variables, that means they can't be final.

Comment: Yes, That's right! Thank you!@AndyTurner@Nathan

Answer (score 0):

A *shared variable* is a placeholder for a location within the shared memory. There might be some confusion due to the fact that you can have an immutable reference variable pointing to an object with mutable instance variables.

But you can always decomposed all object graphs to a set of simple variables. If all these variables are immutable, then the entire object graph is immutable. But if some of these variables are mutable, we may enter the discussion about the possibility of data races if one or more of these variables are modified in one thread and read by another thread.

For this discussion, their place in the complex object graph is irrelevant, which is reason why the discussion uses just two mutable variables, `x` and `y`, apparently of type `int`. They still may be members of a, e.g. a `Point` instance being stored in a `HashMap`, but the only thing that matters is that these `x` and `y` variables are being modified and, as explained in the cited book, the unlocking of `M` will make these modifications visible to any thread subsequently locking `M`, as this applies to *all* variables, regardless of their place within the heap memory or object graph.

Note that the mutable nature of `x` and `y` implies that there might be older values they had before the `x=1` resp. `y=1` assignments, which can show up when being read without synchronization. This includes the default values (`0`) they have before the first assignment.